# Is my stock gone forever from a reverse split / bought by another company?

Tags: stocks, investing, financial-literacy, stock-valuation, stock-split

I'm a complete novice in regards to investing and had purchased some shares of **OXIS** from TD Ameritrade back in March of 2015 (NASDAQ). The company (OXIS International) became very devalued and did a "mandatory reverse split" and changed symbol to **OXISD** in December of that year... assuming it was delisted and moved to OTC?

Since then, the symbol disappeared from my "positions" within TD Ameritrade, as if there is no longer a record of me having anything. It seems the company sold to "GT Biopharma, Inc."

Does this mean I no longer own any shares? If I do, how would I go about finding them?

My final TD Ameritrade transaction history appears as:

- 03/27/2015 - Bought OXIS @ 0.0449
- 12/16/2015 - MANDATORY REORGANIZATION FEE
- 12/16/2015 - MANDATORY REVERSE SPLIT (OXISD)
- 12/17/2015 - MONEY MARKET REDEMPTION

Nothing else since then, however I did look into "statements" and it does show some relation to OXIS INTL:

**Margin Div/Int - Securities Sold OXIS INTL
1:300 R/S 8/21/17 36254L100**

Did they just turn all my previous shares into nothing basically?

Comment: Did you keep a paper trail? Your monthly statements would show whatever the transition was. And - did you ask the broker?  Last - it appears that OXISD  still trades, [article from yesterday](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/gt-biopharma-inc-announces-closing-120500030.html)

Comment: Yes, at least everything within TD Ameritrade account via transaction history.  Updated my question with the results.

Comment: "I'm a complete novice in regards to investing and had purchased some shares of OXIS" That's a very common way of getting experience, although somewhat costly.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[GT BIOPHARMA, INC. ANNOUNCES REVERSE STOCK SPILT AS PART OF OXIS-GEORGETOWN PLANNED MERGER](http://www.oxis.com/news-media/press-releases/detail/117/gt-biopharma-inc-announces-reverse-stock-spilt-as-part-of)

> LOS ANGELES, CA / ACCESSWIRE / August 21, 2017 / GT Biopharma Inc.
>   (formerly known as Oxis International, Inc.) announced today a
>   1-for-300 reverse stock split. Shareholders of GT Biopharma Inc.
>   (OTCQB: OXIS and Euronext Paris: OXI.PA) will be issued 1 share of
>   common stock for every 300 shares common stock that they owned.

If you owned fewer than 300 shares, they cashed you out.

Comment: Ok, I do see what's happened.  This seems to be the 2nd reverse split since I had the account. Basically my shares have fallen to be worth absolutely nothing.  After the 1st split, my 11k shares dropped to 44.  Now with this 2nd split - the shares are just evaporating to nothing as per Aganju's comment below, as I can't own fractional shares- correct?

Comment: Sorry, fellow Joe, that's about it. It's happened to all of us eventually.

Comment: @Joe well not into nothing. You should have been cashed out.

Comment: His statement said Money market Redemption. Probably too small a dollar amount to notice among interest and dividends, but you are right, 'cashed out'.

Comment: @Joe In case you are curious why they did this: reading that announcement it seems that they are looking to get listed on the NASDAQ which just so happens to require a share (bid) price of at least $4.

Comment: So effectively they bought back all of his sub-300 shares, without his consent to sell.

Comment: @Joe If your original holding went from 11k to 44 shares then that's a 1-250 split and must be what happened at the end of 2015 ([this press release from 2016](http://www.oxis.com/news-media/press-releases/detail/86/oxis-eliminates-debt-in-restructuring-deal-will-move) seems to touch on this, but doesn't give all details). With only 44 shares, the second reverse split in August couldn't grant you a whole "new" share, so they should have been sold at whatever the going rate was at the time. The current price seems to be ~$10, so possibly 44 "old" shares would have been around $1.46 in total.

Comment: @jiggunjer You are always at the mercy of a majority shareholder vote to do something you personally disapprove of. It's just one of those things that comes as part of the deal. And, sadly, getting a dollar or so back in cash is better than having a holding which is likely worth less than the trading fee.

Comment: @jiggunjer: Some brokers allow you to set a rounding policy for fractional shares (always buy, always sell, sell if less than half a share). But even if there's no policy, the broker has to do _something_. Either they buy the missing fraction for you, or they sell.

Answer (score 19):

You can't own fractional shares.
If the *Reverse Split* resulted in you having less a full share (for example, if you had 500 shares, and they did a 1000:1 reverse split), your fractional share was cashed in (sold). That could be that 'money market' activity shown on the next day?

It is your responsibility to be prepared for a reverse split, by either selling at your desired price, or buying more shares, so you end with an integer number of shares after the reverse split.

Comment: Well, you 'can' , but typically not from a reverse split. I have gotten fractional shares as a result of dividend reinvestment. Also from employee stock purchase programs that invested an exact number of dollars and bought fractional shares.

Comment: That would be because your shares are managed by a company. They handle all the fractional shares, and hold the reminder to the full next integer on their own. If you trade individual shares, it's whole shares only.